# Have to hit "Enter" after searching or I lose the pattern

Tags: search, highlight, jump

If I am searching for a word inside a file,
if I do not hit ENTER after the search pattern,
my vi loses the current match and jumps back to where it was.

I have

```
set hlsearch
set incsearch
```

in `.vimrc`.

Therefore, the moment I start typing `word`, vi jumps to the first occurrence and highlights that. However, this tricks me into believing that it really jumped there, so almost by instinct, I hit ESC and do whatever I was supposed to do at that point.

But that cancels my search and puts me back to where I was, which I find slightly annoying.

Can I make vi to jump there right away?

I have not yet thought through if this could have other less agreeable consequences... But I am willing to find out if it's possible.

Comment: Just a note that this is "by design": `/` is essentially an ex-command, which requires Enter to terminate. If you turn off `incsearch` the behavior is perhaps more intuitive (Enter to move), though of course `incsearch` is quite handy, too

Comment: Yeah I think I am getting used to `incsearch`  - I just only recently enabled it. Without it, as you are suggesting, the default behavior seems rather transparent and indeed intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to enable the `x` [cpoption](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cpoptions%27), which makes `<Esc>` execute a command (rather than cancel it) when in command-line mode.

```
set cpoptions+=x
```

See [`:help cpo-x`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo-x) and [`:help c_Esc`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_%3CEsc%3E) for more details.

The traadeoff in this approach is that this makes `<Esc>` execute or confirm in *any* of the command-line modes, including `:` (for Ex command-line, for example `:q<Esc>` will then quit!), also `input()` and a few more modes.

---

In theory, you could add a mapping that only handles `<Esc>` in command-line for searches, with:

```
cnoremap <expr> <Esc> getcmdtype() =~ '^[/?]$' ? '<Enter>' : '<C-C>'
```

Unfortunately, that breaks the use of keys whose key sequence starts with an `<Esc>`, such as arrow keys, in command-line mode. Vim seems to run into this issue whenever you create a mapping for `<Esc>`, there doesn't seem to be an easy or reliable solution for this problem.

(Note also that this last mapping needs to map to `<C-C>` for keeping `<Esc>` behavior in modes other than search, since `<Esc>` in mappings behaves as if the `x` cpoption is set, as mentioned in `:help c_Esc`.)

Comment: It seems to work for now! I will leave the setting for a while and see how this behaves for my other workflows. Thanks!